# Is this diminished II7 or VII in harmonic minor?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, voice-leading, cadence

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpmIV.png): [[image]]

Hi,

I have some problems to analyze 2nd and 4th bar chords in this example in A minor (harmonic). For my understanding, 2nd bar chord can be either diminished chord in ii or vii. What about the first chord in 4th bar (before v chord), is it ii or vii chord? Which diminished chords are used here in this simple chord progression? Thanks

Comment: Hi Janta. Is this homework for a class?

Comment: What are the clefs for these staves?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I would hazard a guess that it's treble clef on top and bass clef underneath based on the existing chord analysis, but there are definitely still inconsistencies in the less disputed chord labels in that case (especially the 2nd chord of Bar 4, claimed to be V).

Comment: Also, what key signature is the example in? (I'd hazard a guess that it has no accidentals and your example is in A minor, but that doesn't quite explain how all your tonic chords are labelled I instead of i.)

Comment: Hi everyone, This is not homework just my analysis of a song. Treble clef on top, bass clef on bottom. No accidentals so it's in A Minor. Chord labels should be in smaller lowercase as it's minor - sorry about that.

Comment: What song is this from? It looks like it has a deceptively fast harmonic rhythm right now - i.e. I'd hazard a guess that Bar 4 might even change chords every *8th note* for more than half of it.

Comment: An answer might be more helpful to you if you added what you feel is the _harmonic reduction_ of the passage. Bar 2 has `B D G#` on all strong downbeats which is reasonable for  a `viio6`. The only `B` or `D` in the bass in bar 4 is the `B` on up beat of beat 3 which does not make a strong case for a `iio` chord.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - A previous edit had Bars 2 and 4 split into 2 chords each, one per every 2 beats. Note my earlier comments doubting that this interpretation was correct.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, OK, but I just want to see how the OP reduces whatever version they are working with. Essentially, their reduction is their analysis. How they perceive that is really the heart of the matter.

Comment: @Michael Curtis, What does harmonic reduction means? I'm just a beginner and still learning the basics of harmony and voice leading. I tend to over-analyze every possible chord within a bar so maybe harmonic reduction is opposite of that?

Comment: @Dekkadeci, My example is a song from the soundtrack of Nier Automata (Grandma - Destruction).

Comment: @Janta, look at the Bach C major prelude and E minor prelude illustrations on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_leading, the staves under the original scores are harmonic reductions.

Comment: @Janta your comment "I tend to over-analyze every possible chord within a bar so maybe harmonic reduction is opposite of that?" more or less, yes, that is the idea. In your example, if you look to every beat or every eighth note moment for chords, it mixes up the harmonic level, you might say harmonic rhythm level, with the figuration details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, the other answers give the basic analysis of the chords in your example. But I think you need to look into harmonic analysis and harmonic reduction. You may be trying to identify chords on too small a time scale - like every beat of even every eight note - but that is not always appropriate. Some related terms to read up on are *harmonic rhythm*, *figuration*, *diminution*, *non-chord tones*.

A harmonic analysis could look like the following where a simplified version of the music is given below the original score...

[image]

That is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_leading

The arrows in that reduction may seem confusing, but they are trying to show something called a *voice exchange*. You can ignore them if it isn't clear.

Also, you can think of *levels* of harmonic action which distinguishes between top level, melodic particulars versus deeper, more abstracted harmonic design, like in this example from the textbook *Kostka, Tonal Harmony*...

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

From comments...

> f a chord in A minor has tones B-D-F-G#, then can it be both iio7 (G# as 7th) and viio chord?

No. You want to read chords in thirds, identify chord roots, then identify inversions.

`B-D-F-G#` if you read that in thirds it will be `G# B D F`, so `G#` is the root and the chord is in first inversion from the `B` in bass. In Roman numeral analysis (RNA) that is `Am: viio6/5`.

For the diminished chord `iio` in minor, the basic triad is `B D F`. It is often in first inversion `D F B`, `D` in bass, RNA `iio6`.

When you get to that chord as a seventh chord things get a little tricky. The `ii` chord in major and the `iio` chord in minor are both *subdominant* function chords, they are not dominant chords. That has bearing on the seventh chord in minor.

The seventh chord spelling in `A` minor is `B D F A`. Notice the seventh above root `B` is an `A`. It's a base diminished triad plus a minor seventh. That chord is called a *half diminished chord.* The RNA symbol uses a slashed circle: `iiø7`. This is the seventh chord on root `ii` in minor. It often is in first inversion `D F A B`, `iiø6/5`.

You can lower the top tone of `B D F A` by a half step to `B D F G#`, but notice that in the key of `A` minor that change from `A` to `G#` is a move from *tonic* to `leading tone` scale degrees. That leading tone is what creates the *dominant* function `viio6/5`.

One half step may seem like a tiny change, but it's an important change. It's the difference between a subdominant function `iiø7` chord and a dominant function `viio7` chord!

If all this stuff about roots, inversions, function, etc. is not familiar, you probably need to get a good harmony textbook to learn the fundamentals of harmony.

Comment: Thank you Michael for providing a lot of helpful information.

Comment: You wrote earlier: "Bar 2 has B D G# on all strong downbeats which is reasonable for a viio6. The only B or D in the bass in bar 4 is the B on up beat of beat 3 which does not make a strong case for a iio chord." This makes sense although I'm still a bit confused with diminished chords in harmonic minor. If a chord in A minor has tones B-D-F-G#, then can it be both iio7 (G# as 7th) and viio chord? I guess there are no hard and fast rules and it all depends on context.

Comment: @Janta, I think I see where you may be having trouble. I added some more to my answer, because it's a long explanation.

Comment: Michael, thanks once again for your help. Your explanation provided the answer to my question!

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze the entire second measure as a `V7` chord. Since the first and third measures are both `I` chords, analyzing m. 2 as `V7` gives a clear accounting of the harmonic motion. The first two beats of that measure comprise a `vii dim` chord in second inversion, but calling it such doesn't significantly change the overall analysis of Tonic – Dominant – Tonic.

I would call m. 4 `V7` for the same reason — the micro-details don't change the overall analysis.

---

For the purpose of attempting to label each chord, then the downbeat of m. 2 is `vii dim` in first inversion, and the downbeat of m. 4 is `ii halfdim7` in third inversion and with the chordal fifth omitted, which is standard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if the harmonic progression is clear like I - V7 here, then you don't have to label each possible chord within a measure?

Comment: @Janta That's right.

Answer (score 0):

The bars are basically i (bar1) V (bar2) i (bar3) and V (bar4). There's nothing particular that changes the basic harmony in each of the four bars. Beats 1 and 3 (the strongest) all allude to those chords, except 3 in bar 4, which waits till beat 4.

A minor is a key; A harmonic minor is a scale.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Now if I only knew when not to over-analyze every possible chord within a bar!

Answer (score 0):

Bar 1 is basically an Am chord.  So is bar 3.  Bar 2 includes a G♯ and all the on-the-beat notes are included in an E7 chord.  Accept the simple analysis!   Bar 4 is a little more complex, but it's still basically E7.

If the environment is A minor, and you find yourself playing E, G♯ and D notes, it's 99% sure there's no point in calling the chord anything but E7.    If the E is specifically omitted, it MIGHT be useful to call it G♯dim.   But, functionally, it's just another flavour of E7, the dominant of Am.

Comment: Thank you Laurence, I'm slowly but surely begin to believe the dominance of V chord!